# Nan values in regression MATLAB

Tags: regression, matlab

I run the following regression:

```
mdl=fitlm(Reg_var(1:end,2:end),Reg_var(1:end,1),'RobustOpts','on')
```

My output:

```
Linear regression model (robust fit): 
y ~ [Linear formula with 21 terms in 20 predictors] 

Estimated Coefficients:

                Estimate          SE          tStat       pValue 
               ___________    __________    _________    ________

(Intercept)      0.0015684    0.00082514       1.9008    0.057371
x1              -0.0025121     0.0011669      -2.1528    0.031375
x2              -0.0011949     0.0011669      -1.0239      0.3059
x3              0.00021162     0.0011669      0.18135      0.8561
x4              -0.0015328     0.0011669      -1.3135     0.18905
x5              -0.0012053     0.0011669      -1.0329      0.3017
x6              -0.0020596     0.0011669      -1.7649    0.077622
x7              -0.0032643     0.0011669      -2.7974    0.005168
x8              0.00031066     0.0011669      0.26622     0.79008
x9              -0.0021079     0.0011669      -1.8063    0.070913
x10            -0.00046861     0.0011669     -0.40158     0.68801
x11            -0.00037094     0.0011659     -0.31816     0.75038
x12            -0.00017788     0.0011669     -0.15243     0.87885
x13            -5.3013e-05     0.0011669    -0.045429     0.96377
x14            -0.00072536     0.0011669      -0.6216     0.53423
x15                      0             0          NaN         NaN
x16            -0.00057762     0.0011669       -0.495     0.62062
x17             -0.0003968     0.0011669     -0.34004     0.73384
x18            -0.00093411     0.0011669     -0.80049     0.42346
x19             -0.0017195     0.0011669      -1.4735     0.14065
x20             -0.0015061    0.00096437      -1.5618     0.11839

Number of observations: 6260, Error degrees of freedom: 6240
Root Mean Squared Error: 0.014
R-squared: 0.0043,  Adjusted R-Squared 0.00127
F-statistic vs. constant model: 1.42, p-value = 0.107
```

Why do I get NaN values at dummy 15 and what does this mean? How can I solve this? What am I doing wrong? Multicolinearity?

Comment: The NANs come from attempts to divide by 0. On that line follow through: estimate = 0, SE = 0, so t = estimate/SE = ?. P-value can't be calculated without t. Implication is that `x15` does not belong in the model. Check whether it varies at all or is collinear with other predictors. But the bottom line from (e.g) your R-squared is that the model doesn't work at all well, so tinkering with it by dropping a predictor is not going to fix that.

Comment: How does x15 look like?

Comment: It is a dummy that takes the value of 1 on the day of the month it is assigned and 0 otherwise. I think I have solved the problem. Stock and Watson "Introduction to Econometrics" 2012 mention the dummy variable trap. Either you remove a dummy or drop the intercept. I dropped the intercept and got reasonable results.

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

The NANs come from attempts to divide by 0. On that line follow through: estimate = 0, SE = 0, so t = estimate/SE = ?. P-value can't be calculated without t. Implication is that x15 does not belong in the model. Check whether it varies at all or is collinear with other predictors. But the bottom line from (e.g) your R-squared is that the model doesn't work at all well, so tinkering with it by dropping a predictor is not going to fix that. – Nick Cox

x15 is a dummy that takes the value of 1 on the day of the month it is assigned and 0 otherwise. I think I have solved the problem. Stock and Watson "Introduction to Econometrics" 2012 mention the dummy variable trap. Either you remove a dummy or drop the intercept. I dropped the intercept and got reasonable results. – user3934760